# Magento 2 instance AccountManagement on Command

Tags: magento2

How can I instance an `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement` inside a Command in a custom module?

I'm trying to create a command to reset all customers passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably just use DI for the `AccountManagementInterface`, like this snippet taken from [Magento's code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ffea3cd/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/ForgotPasswordPost.php#L70-L73):

```
class Command
{
    public function __construct(
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
    ) {
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
    }

    public function whatever() {
        $this->customerAccountManagement->initiatePasswordReset(
            $email,
            AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET
        );
   }
}
```